# I would like to know if there is a way to sync the checkboxes?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

is there a way to sync the checkboxes?

for example my screen :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZXvJ.png)

I'm using the mvvm structure

XAML:

```
<CheckBox 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Content="{lang:Localization Chk_Users}"
    IsEnabled="True"
    IsChecked="{Binding IsUserMigration}" Margin="20,20,20,20"
/>

 <CheckBox 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Content="{lang:Localization Chk_Cards}"
    IsChecked="{Binding IsCardMigration}" Margin="20,6,18,34"
>
```

however I would like to know if there is, for example, if cards are selected, users are also selected automatically

The ViewModel only has the functions to do the migration... nothing related

Comment: Add this logic to your ViewModel, for example in the setter of UserMigration check CardMigration too.

Comment: This is what I'm not getting, as there is no ".Checked" method to check if the value is true...

Comment: _"This is what I'm not getting, as there is no ".Checked" method to check if the value is true..."._ Your ViewModel could have `set`ters; with its .Is*Migration properties, or a `public` Whatever() method that would do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you have a ViewModel like this:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    // Fields to be migrated
    public bool IsUserMigration
    {
        get => _isUserMigration;
        set
        {
            if (_isUserMigration!= value)
            {
                _isUserMigration= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsUserMigration));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsCardMigration
    {
        get => _isCardMigration;
        set
        {
            if (_isCardMigration!= value)
            {
                _isCardMigration= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCardMigration));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to select IsUserMigration every time IsCardMigration is selected, simply set IsUserMigration to true in the setter or IsCardMigration.

```cs
public bool IsCardMigration
{
    get => _isCardMigration;
    set
    {
        if (_isCardMigration!= value)
        {
            _isCardMigration= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCardMigration));
            IsUserMigration = true;
        }
    }
}
```